Particular integral for nth order differential equations with constant coefficients
Say, I have an nth order differential equation with constant coefficients of the form,
$$f(D)y=w(x)$$
Where $f(D)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}D^{k}$
And $D^{k}$ denotes the $k$th derivative and $w$ is complete function in $x$.
I need to show that solutions to such equations are of the form,
$$y=p(x)+c(x)........(1)$$
Where $p(x)$ is particular integral and $c(x)$ is complementary function.
I can solve the equation when $x=0$ by putting $y=ke^{rx}$. This gives me the complementary function too.
And my professor said that,
$$p(x)=\frac{w(x)}{f(D)}$$
My question:-
How to prove that solutions are of the form as mentioned in (1)?

apply f(D) to (1). You see that c(x) is any function such that f(D) c(x) = 0.
